# creating public key and private key using Terraform in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have two ec2. One in public subnet and other in private. I am able to connect to the public ec2 and would like to connect to the ec2 in the private subnet using the private key. Here are my steps using terraform to create the keys-

```
1. resource "tls_private_key" "pk" {
  algorithm = "RSA"`
  rsa_bits = 4096
}
2.
  resource "aws_key_pair" "pk" {
  key_name   = "myKey"       # Create a "myKey" to AWS!!
  public_key = tls_private_key.pk.public_key_openssh } -- tried trimspace also 

3. Created and ec2 and used the above key to create the ec2 in private subnet using 

resource "aws_instance" "xxx" {
----
key_name = aws_key_pair.pk.key_name
} 

4. Stored the private key in SSM ( parameter store) 

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "priv_key" {
name = 
---
value = tls_private_key.pk.private_key_pem 
}
5. Now from the ec2 on public subnet, I did a get parameter to get the private key and tried 
ssh -i /.... ec2-user@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

**I am getting permission denied on public key**

what could be the issue ? is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

AWS docs provides full documentation on that:

- [I'm receiving "Permission denied (publickey)" or "Authentication failed, permission denied" errors when trying to access my EC2 instance. How do I resolve this?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-fix-permission-denied-errors/)

Basically you have to ensure that your keys have correct permissions as explained in the doc above.

Comment: Well, I am unable to login to the ec2 in private subnet.  Another question, when using the above method where is terraform creating the public key? is it under the root user - ~.ssh/authorized_keys. Is it possible to change the directory location ? should I try doing all these in userdata ?

Comment: @Judi Location of `authorized_keys` depends on your operating system. For example, in ubuntu it will be `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Not sure what you are doing, which results in your error. Usually the keys are set properly on aws provided operating systems. Its difficult to know what you are doing wrong, as your question does not provide any details of what OS are you using and there is no full TF code.